# Count number of times entity is referenced in association table

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

With the following tables:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)

class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=False)
    people = db.relationship('Person', secondary=people, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('groups', lazy=True))

people = db.Table(
    'people',
    db.Column('person_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('group_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('group.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

I am trying to write a query that will return me the number of times each person appears in a group.

#### What I need the query to return with example

- I have two entries in Person: Bob and Alice
- Bob is referenced in 5 groups
- Alice is referenced in 4 groups

I would want the query to return something like the following:

```
_____________________________________________
| Person   |  Number of groups referenced in |
|__________|_________________________________|
| Bob      |                  5              |
|__________|_________________________________|
| Alice    |                  4              |
|__________|_________________________________|
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I have tried the following:

```
result = db.session.query(Person.name, db.func.count(people.c.person_id).label('total')).join(people).all()
```

But I'm receiving one result of a single name with a count of all records in the table.

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @VaniGupta I'm unsure how to structure my query, I am quite new to SQLAlchemy and usually work in raw SQL

Comment: @VaniGupta I've updated the question with my attempt and the problem I'm getting